# Redis vs. DocumentDB?

Tags: redis, azure-cosmosdb

I'm pretty new to all this stuff and was reading about Redis Cache and DocumentDB in Azure.

So my question is what is the difference between them and when do you use for example DocumentDB over Redis or the other way around.

I thought maybe someone could simplify the answer a bit further?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis is a networked in-memory key-value (think hashmap) store, with optional durability - it's primary use-case is in-memory caching. Key-value stores provide limited queryability - generally, only allowing queries by primary key (e.g. id). There are few other key-value stores that offer a limited number of secondary indices.

DocumentDB is a durable multi-model NoSQL database, that incorporates elements from document-oriented and other data models. A notable difference with DocumentDB, is that it gives you the ability to query over flexible schemas (without having to define indices or schemas upfront). This is useful in scenarios where you need the ability to query over heterogeneous data (records that have varying attributes, e.g. a product catalog) and/or deal with rapidly evolving schemas (e.g. logging events and telemetry).

I should also point out - that as a write-optimized latch-free database designed specifically to run on high-performance SSDs, DocumentDB provides some interesting latency characteristics: <10ms reads @ P99 and <15ms writes @ P99.